# Find ID of UpdatePanel that contains AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, autocomplete

I am using Ajax Autocomplete to look up student names and return the student ID. My update panel looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="StudentSearchUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <dl>
            <dt>Enter student ID:</dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:TextBox ID="StudentIDTextBox" runat="server" Wrap="False" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="SelectStudentIDButton" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="SelectStudentIDButton_Click"  />
                <asp:Label ID="StudentIDEntryError" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Text="Please enter a 6-digit student ID number."></asp:Label>
            </dd>
            <dt>Or, begin typing student last name:</dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="StudentNameSearchTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></dd>
        </dl>


        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="StudentNameSearchTextBox_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="StudentNameSearchTextBox" 
            ServiceMethod="GetStudents"
            OnClientPopulated="getStudents_Populated_Json"
            OnClientItemSelected="selected_Student" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
            CompletionSetCount="20" 
            UseContextKey="True" >
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

GetStudents_Populated_Json looks like this:

```
    function getStudents_Populated_Json(sender, e) {
        var students = sender.get_completionList().childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        var student = eval('(' + students[i]._value + ')');
         students[i].innerHTML = student.LastName + ' ' + student.FirstName;
      }
```

And finally, selected_student:

```
 function selected_Student(sender, e) {    
      var selectedStudent = eval("(" + e._value + ")");  
 }
```

In selected_student I want to find the ID of the UpdatePanel (StudentSearchUpdatePanel) so I can in turn find "StudentIDTextBox" and place  selectedStudent.ID in StudentIDTextBox.innerHTML.
How do I identify the StudentIDTextBox and set it's innerHTML from selected_Student?

(the student class is ID, FirstName, LastName. I have verified that selectedStudent.ID gives an acurate id).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution would be to make it easy to find the ID of the textbox you want if the first place.

One way of doing this would be to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your `asp:TextBox`. This will force the control of having the same `id` attribute on the client as the server name for the control. That way, to find this control on the client (using JS), you would just:

```
var myTextbox = document.getElementById('StudentNameSearchTextBox');
myTextbox.value = student.LastName + ' ' + student.FirstName;
```

Hope that helps.